# How to create regex in javascript for an api uri to get query parameters with name and values when / is added before?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Example API - /api/test/regex/?name=ciara
What i want - name=ciara

Comment: Hey @sweetie, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I tried: ~^.+\/(?<s>\w.+)$ $s;

Comment: Depending on how complex your URL string gets, you can produce your result quite simply by doing: `"/api/test/regex/?name=ciara".split("?")[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=\?name=)\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kbdLPS/1)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use capturing group here, because a repeated capture group will only store the last match that it found. Every time it makes a match, it will overwrite the previous match with the one it just found.
So, we need to go with 2 step solution, first we validate the URL, then use `matchAll` to find all references:

```
const regexp = /(?:(?:\&|\?)([^=]+)\=([^&]+))/g;
const str = '/api/test/regex/?name=ciara&p=q&r=s&t=u';

const array = [...str.matchAll(regexp)];

console.log(array);
```

This will give you:

```
> Array [Array ["?name=ciara", "name", "ciara"], Array ["&p=q", "p", "q"], Array ["&r=s", "r", "s"], Array ["&t=u", "t", "u"]]
```

Since we have an array now, we just need to iterate it to get all query params.

Following `regex` can be used validate existence of proper query strings:

```
\/?\?([^=]+)\=([^&]+)(?:\&([^=]+)\=([^&]+))*$
```